# What statistical analysis was actually used ? Is this the most appropriate?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, linear

I have a quick query to which I am reviewing a paper that used data from the English Longitudinal Study of Ageing. They mentioned that they conducted "Linear mixed (random coefficient) model to look at the association between Exposure and 6 repeated measures of word recall over a 10 year follow up that was gradually adjusted for covariates". Now in all my years of looking at papers and assessing their statistical analysis and design i've never seen such a complex model. Mind you it is a longitudinal study where they also a multistage stratified random probability design to recruit participants.
Would someone be able to help tease out for me in a simpler way what they did statistically to analyse their data and whether this was most appropriate.

Its slightly hard to parse out exactly what they did because they do not properly explain the actual estimating equation. So I would really love some guidance and help.

I would love to know what every one else thinks.
The link to the paper is: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0175827# Title of paper: Type 2 diabetes, depressive symptoms and trajectories of cognitive decline in a national sample of community-dwellers: A prospective cohort study

Comment: From my quick look at the paper, the study sample was recruited using multistage stratified random probability design, but this was not taken into account in the analysis.

Comment: Hi thank you for response, would you mind further expanding on how they didn’t take the multistage stratified random probability design into account? And how they should have done this?

Comment: You take the sampling into account using (for example) the survey package in R. Some info, for example, here: http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/survey-wss.pdf . But I don't know how to combine that with the rest of the analysis that they did.

Comment: The analysis they did appears to be fairly standard for this sort of thing, although it is hard to describe clearly in the confines of a journal article.  The book Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis, by Singer and Willett https://books.google.com/books/about/Applied_Longitudinal_Data_Analysis.html?id=PpnA1M8VwR8C covers it. (As do lots of other sources).

Comment: I'll try to find the time (and remember) to write an answer which explains more. [Disclaimer: I have worked with one of the authors, Arie Nouwen, and have been an editor of this journal.]

Comment: Thank you so much for your input that you have given thus far!

Comment: @JeremyMiles Hi Jeremy I had a quick question that I thought you may be able to answer in faster time. Do you know if there is any differences in the way R's survey package handles multistage stratified random sampling in comparison to the way SPSS's package handles it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I believe that they are the same.